# The minimum size of the angular main component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

I am using Angular 17. I was wondering if there is a simple way of setting up minimum size of the main angular component (usually called `AppComponent`). I would like to restrict the user from scaling down my main component to the certain size so my components still look recognizable.

Answer (score 0):

To your style you can add :

```
:host {
   display: block;
   min-height: 300px;
   min-width: 300px;
}
```

This will style the host component itself !

Comment: I added that to app.components.less but I can resize my component to zero height